# What Tetration Algorithm can I utilize

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms, fractals, tetration, hyperoperation

I am trying to write program, that builds fractal, like a mandelbrot, but somewhat special... I could explain my "thought flow":

A mandelbrot fractal (I call it **"operation order 1"**) is done by iteratively calculating complex number $Z(n+1) = Z(n)^2 + C$, $Z(0)=0$, $C$ is zoomed and offset screen coordinate. After an infinite number of steps (supertask) we do determine, wherether series for a pixel - does series converge or diverge? and "how fast" does it diverges? Faster are colored by blue, slower - by white. For non-divergent $C$ pixels, belonging to Mandelbrot Set - are black:

[image]

Then, we may proceed to next order, in hyperoperation sequence, and produce **"operation order 2"** fractal, by iterated exponentiation $Z(n+1)=c\exp(Zn)*C$, basically resulting in this:

[image]
[image]

You may increase to the next, order 3 fractal, and get tetration fractal by doing `Z(n+1)=cpow(ctet(some_const, Z(n)),C)`. But I virtually ran into a wall.. NO traces of **how can I write** `ctet(base,height)` function, for integer base, but complex height..

It's EASY to write for complex base and positive integer height: it's just equal to `base^(base^(base^...` and do it `height` times. But I need that not only for `height` being positive integers, but for `height` being complex argument. And base being.. $2.0$, or $e$, or whatever constant, that would just be convenient (that's of minor importance for the fractal structure, rather than bringing `height` variable to complex space)

That is called analytic continuation, or somehow similar. I am not interested in getting big numbers, but rather in *iterating and detecting "Does it converge or diverge?", and, secondary "How many iterations does it take to diverge?"*

Can you offer it in simple words, without going really heavy math?

Ive found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308409/operational-details-implementation-of-knesers-method-of-fractional-iteration/2308955#2308955) but I really fail to understand what is he doing, with insane symbols that aren't easily understandable by programmer on "how to convert that to code". and his taylor series has only X variable, but `ctet(base,height)` hyperoperation should take 2 arguments indeed..

Comment: Tetration is hard to study for complex heights; very hard. We just recently proved there is a unique tetration for complex powers and real bases greater than $e^{1/e}$. You may be able to code something up without knowing the math, but I would try to learn some of it

Comment: If *base* $b$ is real and $1 \lt b \lt \exp(\exp(-1)) \approx 1.44 $ then you can define fractional and even complex heights meaningfully and with not too difficult pregramming with some appropriate software (for instance Pari/GP providing complex arithmetic with arbitrary precision, series etc). Keyword is here "Schroeder-function" (or "Koenigs-function"). I've provided a couple of examples for this in answers here in MSE and in MO.

Comment: Perhaps this link helps/gives first tools to approximations of tetration see https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Super-logarithm

Comment: Just out of curiosity: were you able to do some progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer, just a comment, but having an image in it*

Here is an example of complex heights. I've the base $b=4$, initial value $z_0=4$ . Then -in steps of 128- computations for heights $h=1, \cdots, h=I , \cdots, h=-1 , \cdots, h=-I , \cdots, h=1$ with $h$ on the complex unit circle. (The computations are done with a version of the Kneser-ansatz for bases $b$ larger than $b=e=\exp(1)$ (the choice in Kneser's original text) programmed by the tetration-forum member S. Levenstein).
You might not yet have an idea how iteration with complex heights looks in a trajectory. Here is one picture.

[image]

You can see, that from $z_k= \;^{\exp(2\pi I \cdot k/128)}4$  with $k=0$ and $z_0=4$ the trajectory does roughly an egg-formed path via $z_{64}=0$ back to $z_{128}=4=z_0$.
I don't know whether such a trajectory would really be useful for your project-intentions... Is it anyway?

---

*remark: I'd like more to use the notation* 
$$ \exp_{\log 4}^{\circ h_k} (z) \text{ with } h_k=\exp(2 \pi I \cdot k/128) \text{ and } z=1
$$
*but for whatever reason the public prefers the less expressive notation $^h 4$ .*

---

*remark 2: the legend of the image does not perfectly fit.

In the title it should be* "$\small \exp(2*Pi*î*k/128)$ for $\small k=0..128$"
*and the x/y-legends should contain "z" instead of "x".

It's an older picture, just reused.*

Comment: Ofc,  If we would manage to get the formula of `ctet(z, x)` to get complex `z` tetrated to complex `x` - that could produce an interesting and complicated fractal, that was never seen by human yet! I do think that's worth some prize!

Comment: You may be somewhat close to it.. I am in need for algorithm not for `ctet(4,x)` but for arbitary `z`, and `z` is small..

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make sure that's really what you want... I thought it might be that that closed curve uncovers some otherwise hidden problems... The code for the computation is due to Sheldon Levenstein as given to the tetration-forum and written in Pari/GP. I have a much simpler idea how to compute this, but what gives at best approximations to some 5 to 10 decimal digits to SL's computations. It involves matrix-diagonalization and complex arithmetic (which is possible for instance in Pari/GP)

Comment: To get it "in graphics" and fast, this operation would better be performed on the GPU, with means of OpenCL, or (even better for my particular "visualisation case") - in GLSL, [right within the browser, even from android mobile phone](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4df3Rn). But I havent ever heard about pari/GP - its not a common and known language, as C/C++/GLSL may be to an average programmer and matematician. How can we similarly run that program and get such an 2D colored image (preferably, with hardware acceleration)?

Comment: Pari/GP can be used as a nice interpreter language in style of C and "for nerds" also can be used in *.dll-mode, its functions being called by your surrounding main-C-program. The internal plotting-possibilities are not much developed, I think it calls Gnu-plot as subroutines or external program for plotting. You can get it at http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/ it is still under very active development. If you have multiprecision and complex-number routines you should be able to re-engineer the tetration-functionality in your program anyway. I use Pari/GP because it makes it easy to explore math.