# Find the function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-equations

> Find a function $f(x)$ such that $$f(f(x))=e^x$$

Whenever I encounter these type of questions, for instance $f(f(x))=x$, I take the help of graphs. But in this question, when I draw a graph the problem becomes exceedingly complicated, because the graph of $e^x$ is not a straight line. So, I thought of a different approach.

---

Consider the power series expansion of $f(x)$

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots$$

Substituting this expression into itself for $x,$ and collecting terms by powers of $x,$ we can equate the resulting coefficients to the corresponding coefficients of $e^x.$ This gives a set of conditions on the derivatives of $f$ at $0$ and $a_0.$ Letting $f_n(x)$ denote the $nth$ derivative of $f$, we have the conditions,

$$f_0(a_0) = 1$$

$$ f_1(0) f_1(a_0) = 1$$

$$ f_2(0) f_1(a_0) + f_1(0)^2 f_2(a_0) = 1$$

and so on.

---

After this, I'm stuck. I'm not able to think how to continue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I advise you Google queries with keywords "compositional square root"

Comment: Given $x$ is in the exponent, what different power laws can one manipulate?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283500/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135474/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59023/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65876/42969 and probably more can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(f(z))%20%3D%20e%5Ez%24)